# C++11: Swapping array name and index

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Older compilers allowed this kind of "blasphemy"

```
int a[5];
4[a] = 3;
```

Simply because operator[] would allow const expression and those are equal:

```
*(4 + a) === *(a + 4)
```

Is that a defined behavior or an UB in C++11?

Edit: answer:

> Except where it has been declared for a class (13.5.5), the subscript operator [] is interpreted in such a way that E1[E2] is
>   identical to *((E1)+(E2)). Because of the conversion rules that apply
>   to +, if E1 is an array and E2 an integer, then E1[E2] refers to the
>   E2-th member of E1. Therefore, despite its asymmetric appearance,
>   subscripting is a commutative operation.

Comment: Note, however, that most containers do not support this kind of syntax.

Comment: @Brian "Except where it has been declared for a class". Containers declare subscript usually. SO it isn't declared and can't b used or it works differently. That's obvious