# C++ literal followed by a bracket

Tags: c++

I came across this code I have no clue what it is doing

```
// ptr is a pointer to an int
if (2[ptr] == 5){
    // do something
}
```

I did some of my tests but no matter what value I pass into ptr, 0, negatives, positives, `2[ptr]` always evaluates to 0. I am surprised it actually compiles. Can someone explain what this expression is ?

Comment: Where did you "come across" this code? Who wrote it? Why don't you ask them what it does, and why?

Comment: Whoever wrote code using that syntax should not be allowed to deliver code to the codebase anymore :)

Comment: `2[ptr]` is evaluated as `*(ptr+2)`

Comment: @BoundaryImposition You don't have to ask them what it does or why they did it: simply fire them on the spot :-)

Comment: lol it's more like a code snippet for fun in school to test c++ knowledge. This is absolutely not readable for any production code haha

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Exit interviews ;)

Comment: This kind of code only exists in puzzles and intentionally obfuscated code.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273307/c11-swapping-array-name-and-index for more

Comment: @Barmar I saw only once when this syntax was used legitimately, but there both  index and pointer were results of function calls and braces wre used like scope braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2[ptr]` is the same as `ptr[2]` (more or less). Somebody is playing a little joke on you.

As for why it always evaluates to 0, that depends on the rest of the program, which we cannot see.